# checking whether a number is prime

Tags: python, for-loop, primes

i am trying to create a for loop that goes through numbers in within range and check if they are divisible. Here is my code:

```
user_input = input("pick a number")

for i in range(1, int(user_input)):
    if int(user_input) % i == 0 and i != 1 and i != int(user_input):
        print("Your number is prime")
    else:
        print("your number is not prime")
```

the second condition keeps getting executed even for prime numbers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You test `i != 1`. The very first loop will always have `i == 1`, therefore, it will tell you it is not prime. You definitely shouldn't be reporting *anything* as prime within the loop though; you don't know it's prime until you've ruled out all possible factors. Change your `range` to start at `2`, not `1`, and remove that part of the test, and have it report *not* prime when it's evenly divisible (right now you're reporting prime when it *is* evenly divisible, which is nuts).

Comment: Whether the condition is met or not you will go round the loop again and again. The logic is wrong - think about what should be in the loop and what should be done after the loop. Each input should produce one print statement.

Answer (score 1):

When you use a for loop, you are iterating the number of times that are in `range(1, int(user_input))` and so your `if/else` gets executed over and over again, and in each iteration is printing something. Instead you only want to print when you are done.

To pull this off, you want to use a boolean True/False variable to track if the number is prime or not, and set it accordingly in your `for` loop.

```
user_input = input("pick a number")

is_prime = True
for i in range(2, int(user_input)):
    if int(user_input) % i == 0 :
        is_prime = False
        break #break out of the for loop since the number isn't prime

if is_prime:
   print("Your number is prime")
else:
   print("your number is not prime")
```

Some other small changes:

1. Removed condition `and i != 1` as any iteration past `1` would fail this test and you want to check EVERY number in your iterations
2. Removed condition `and i != int(user_input)` since in your iterations you will never reach this number `range()` is not inclusive of the highest number.
3. Added a `break` once we determine that the number is not a prime so we don't waste iterations checking if it's even more not-prime.

Comment: Note: Python has an `else:` case for `for` loops, so you can remove the `is_prime` flag entirely. In the case when you `break` (because it's not prime), you can print there, and when it is prime, you won't have `break`-ed, so you can report it's prime in the `for`'s `else`. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY49DsIwDIX3nMIKQjQSA9ANqQdhQm3l0qjFjvIz9PQhSasCXmz5PX/PZvEjUx1jcGifmkzw0IAmX5W5kkb3E7RA4d2hlUoJIQa2oJMHbEsvrG7n4v8ClLoLSKUH@KEe003TwGXVchmb7@TCwW580A6IfVbeKNXu7Cy2ExzWxgnGA/gRIX8yMxtwmnosqx1Ep40jcHZYUrfAx3/gFhbjtf4A "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: Also, the conversion to `int` should definitely be done outside the loop (`user_input = int(input("pick a number"))`, removing all other calls to `int`); repeatedly converting from string to `int` is adding a bunch of pointless work (this isn't your fault, the OP has the same inefficiency).

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code range should be  2 not 1. Add a break statemnt once condition satisfies.

```
user_input = input("pick a number")
user_input  = int(user_input)

for i in range(2, user_input)::  #for i in range(2, int(user_input /2)+1) also works
    if (user_input  % i) == 0:    
        print("Your number is prime")
        break
else:
    print("Your number is not a prime")
```

More simpler approch

```
user_input = int(input("pick a number"))
result = all(user_input % i for i in range(2, user_input))

if result:
     print("Your number is prime")
else:
     print("Your number not a is prime")
```